# Suggest a 'headless' linux dist that I can use to play with firefox, Xvfb and selenium RC?

Tags: linux, virtualization, headless

I'd like to build a similar replica of the virtual server I get from my hosting company in order to test a windowless application of firefox using Xvfb.

I'd like to do so using a parallels virtual machine on OSX.

I'm happy to run some commands to get info but I'm pretty much a linux noob so be gentle!

At the moment this is all I really know:

`GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-46)` on linux2

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to get a copy of CentOS 5. This is basically Red Hat Enterprise Linux (which your server appears to be), but without the money charged by Red Hat. CentOS builds all the source from the same packages as Red Hat.

See http://www.centos.org/modules/tinycontent/index.php?id=15